# Ember JS: Get data from one component to another component

Tags: ember.js

I defined some fixed data in my ember component ‘One’, like this:

```
// coponents/component-one.js

import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({

someData: [
    { name: "Test A", numbers: [1,2,3,4,5] },
    { name: "Test B", numbers: [6,7,8,9,10] },
    { name: "Test C", numbers: [11,12,13,14,15] },
    ],

    // my functions ... 

});
```

Now I have another component, component ‘Two’, where I want to do something like this:

```
// templates/coponents/component-two.hbs

    {{#each someData as |data|}}
        <span>{{data.name}}</span>
    {{/each}}
```

... how can I access *someData* in *component-two.js/component-two.hbs* ?

I do not know how to get.this ...

Comment: What is the connection between `component-one` to `component-two` ?. did you include `component-two` in `component-one` ? In general you need to pass required data while including components

Comment: no, that’s the problem: both components are on the same level, kind of parallel ...

Comment: Then owner of the data is not `component-one` then consider keeping it parent may be corresponding controller or route.

Comment: This works! Great, thanks! (Probably it would be better to establish a model for `someData`, right?) All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define array properties inside `init` method, so that this will ensure every instance will get fresh data.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.set('someData', [
            { name: "Test A", numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
            { name: "Test B", numbers: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] },
            { name: "Test C", numbers: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15] },
        ])
    }

    // my functions ... 

});
```

I assume, you want to include `component-two` in `component-one`. in that case you need to pass the required data,

```
{{component-two someData=someData }}
```

Refer https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/

Comment: For the fact that `component-one` and `component-two` are on the same level I put this into `application.js` so it works for both! Thanks