# How to call a function in a component from another component n ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am in a print-user component after I click edit button I am redirecting edit-user component.
I have to send the data from print-user to edit-user.
So I am calling the edit-user component-class function from print-user component-class.
But it is showing the error

app/components/print-user.hbs

```
</input5>
    <table class="styled-table">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>User Id</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Mailid</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {{#each this.dummyresponse.Users_data as |user|}}
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.mailid}}</td>
                    <LinkTo @route="edit-user" ><button {{on "click" (fn edituser user.id user.firstname user.lastname user.mailid )}} >Edit</button>r</LinkTo></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
{{yield}}
```

app/components/print-user.js

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import {action} from "@ember/object";
import {tracked} from "@glimmer/tracking";
import EditUserComponent from './edit-user';
export default class PrintUserComponent extends Component {
    @tracked dummyresponse="";
    @action 
    async printuser (){
        let response=await fetch("/UserManagement/SearchServlet",
        {   method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "type": "",
                "searchtext": ""
            })
        });
        this.dummyresponse=await response.json();
        
    }
    edituser (id,firstname,lastname,mailid){
        alert("print-user.js entered");
        console.log(EditUserComponent.edituser(id,firstname,lastname,mailid));
        alert("print-user.js after method call entered");
    }
}
```

app/components/edit-user.hbs

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class EditUserComponent extends Component {

    async edituser (id,firstname,lastname,mailid){
        alert("edit-user.js entered");
        let response=await fetch("/UserManagement/UserManagementServlet",
        {   method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "type": "edit",
                "id": id,
                "firstname":firstname,
                "lastname":lastname,
                "mailid":mailid
            })
        });
    }
}
```

app/components/edit-user.js

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class EditUserComponent extends Component {

    async edituser (id,firstname,lastname,mailid){
        alert("edit-user.js entered");
        let response=await fetch("/UserManagement/UserManagementServlet",
        {   method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "type": "edit",
                "id": id,
                "firstname":firstname,
                "lastname":lastname,
                "mailid":mailid
            })
        });
    }
}
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: _editUser.default.edituser is not a function
    at Proxy.edituser (print-user.js:88)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (runtime.js:7105)
```

Comment: please post your required code where error is coming

Comment: did you add route for edituser component in app/router.js?

Comment: Yes i Added route for edit-user in route.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42677815

Comment: If I press Edit in print-user.hbs. It will redirect to edit-user.hbs. I have to update the data given by the user in edit-user.hbs using the mailid from print-user

for e-g:
Userid Fname   Lname   mailid
1            Hari       Doss    hari@gmail.com     Edit
if I press Edit here It will redirect to edit-user.hbs and ask me to enter the data to be modified. If user gave 
Userid     Fname     Lname     mailid
   1             Doss        Hari         hari@gmail.com
based on the mailid in print-user.hbs i have to update the data in Database.

Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `edituser` method of `EditUserComponent` as a static method in `edituser` method of `PrintUserComponent`. Simplified your code looks like this:

```js
import EditUserComponent from './edit-user';
console.log(EditUserComponent.edituser(id,firstname,lastname,mailid));
```

You aren't calling `edituser` method on an instance of the class but on the class itself. Maybe you are looking for a good old utility function instead?

```js
// app/utils/edituser.js

async function edituser (id,firstname,lastname,mailid){
    alert("edit-user.js entered");
    let response=await fetch("/UserManagement/UserManagementServlet",
    {   method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "type": "edit",
            "id": id,
            "firstname":firstname,
            "lastname":lastname,
            "mailid":mailid
        })
    });
}

export default edituser;
```

That utility function could be used like this:

```js
import edituser from '../utils/edituser';
console.log(edituser(id,firstname,lastname,mailid));
```

Components should only be invoked in templates. So they are for sure not what you want.